# TinyMCE on single property with different themes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I’ve installed TinyMCE into an MVC project via Nuget and set an EditorFor to use it, by following this tutorial: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

The problem I have now is I want to be able to use it on one property in two different places with different themes, simple in one place and advanced in another.

This is what I have in my modal to have TinyMCE display for my PageContent property:

```
[UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
public object PageContent { get; set; }
```

Can I do this on a single property so I can toggle at will between advanced and simple when needed?

e.g.. being able to use this from time to time?

```
[UIHint("tinymce_jquery_simple"), AllowHtml]
public object PageContent { get; set; }
```

I’m using EF with Database first as a Modal so the Modal above is in a partial/MetaData class.